# Powershell Select-String with Loop and Cut to .dat

Tags: powershell, loops, export-to-csv, select-string

first of all, i´m sorry for my bad english

i´m completely new to powershell and not so into programming, but i´m willing to learn

So my problem is:

I got a .conf data with textes like this:

```
[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
room a201*,f110
XYZXYZXYZ
XYZXYZXYZ
XYZXYZXYZ
XYZXYZXYZ

[XYZ2 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
room a202*,f110
XYZXYZXYZ
XYZXYZXYZ
XYZXYZXYZ
```

My goal is to export the text into a csv or other data like this:

```
a201,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
f110,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
a202,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
f110,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
```

So for each text with the [] brackets, it should take the room (line under) and check, if there is another room (a201,f110), remove the word "room" and the other lines under and the star "*" and export it like above.

My first step was something like that:

```
Select String -input C:\xyz\text.conf -pattern "\[*\]","room  *" | select line
```

Then i tried to remove the word "room" with Substring, but that didnt work, and i have no idea how to make a loop for each room and export that into 2 columns.

I hope you guys can help me.

Greets Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might be one solution. This uses the `Context` property of `Select-String` to retain the previous line where you can then split and replace the searched line to get the desired output.

```
Select-String -input C:\xyz\text.conf -pattern 'room' -Context 1,0 | % {
    $current = $_
    $current.Line -split ',' | % {
      "$($_ -replace 'room ' -replace '\*'),$($current.Context.PreContext)"
    }
}
```

**Test script**

```
("[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]",
"room a201*,f110",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"",
"[XYZ2 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]",
"room a202*,f110",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"XYZXYZXYZ",
"XYZXYZXYZ") | 
    sls 'room' -Context 1,0 | % {
        $current = $_
        $current.Line -split ',' | % {"$($_ -replace 'room ' -replace '\*'),$($current.Context.PreContext)"}
    }
```

**Output**

```
a201,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
f110,[XYZ1 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
a202,[XYZ2 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
f110,[XYZ2 - XYZXYZ, XYZXYZ]
```

Comment: That helped me so much, thank you a lot, minutes after i posted my question, i found the -replace function, but didnt know i could use is twice in one line